# steps to update third party jar

Tags: java, jar

What's the best practice if I have a third party jar. I want to update some code inside that jar and repackage the jar and use the modified jar in my project?
I'm trying to update some class in `jersey-server.jar` (version 2.22.1). Thanks

Comment: It's often possible to extend the functionality of a library in a way that the library intended your to do it using their API. I suggest that you ask specifically about the modification that you want to make; people here may know a way to achieve what you want *without* modifying the jar file or changing the source code of the library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifying third-party jars is the opposite of a best practice. However, [jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) is opensource; so you could get the code, modify it and then build from source (which is usually called *forking*).